# How to read stdout from a FILE* created with libexpect in C++ on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, expect

Using C++ I created a FILE* using libexpect:

```
FILE* fd = exp_popen("ssh root@sunblaze");
```

I got to the command line using:

```
exp_fexpectl(fp , exp_exact , "password: " , 1 , exp_end);
```

Now the other posses in bash shell and I want to get the contents of a file there,
so I have to run the command `cat /port1/port`  and get all it prints in a char buffer.
How do I do that?

`fgets` doesn't seem to work...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably use std::fstream instead of the C IO library.

Comment: What is /port1/port ? simple file or some device port, like /dev/ttyS0 ?

Comment: /port1/port a soft link to a proc file, it returns hardware parameters

Comment: and how do i get an std::fstream from a FILE*?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your machine and "sunblaze" are within a firewalled off, reasonably secure environment, I would use "ssh-keygen" and "ssh-copy-id root@sunblaze" to allow your user ID to log in to sunblaze without a password. That way, you don't have a password in your code that someone can look at.

Yes, I know, this wasn't what you were asking...

I don't actually see why `fgets(str, size, fd);` - I will have a little play to figure out...

This definitely works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tcl8.5/expect.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    char str[512];
    FILE *f = exp_popen("ssh user@mybox ls -lR");
    if (f==NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(str, sizeof(str)-1, f))
    {
        printf("%s", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, if the output from ssh doesn't have a newline, obviously, fgets() won't complete. When I first tried, it got stuck on a password question - but when I changed it to a machine that I can log in to without a password, it worked fine.

Comment: I just posted something that reads all the files in "user@mybox" home directory. It works [with a passwordless entry as per `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: your solution works if all you want is to run is one command, I want to leave the connection open and get the data from there when ever i want.
I tried to get 1 by 1 chars with "fgets" and stop when i reach the prompt but that didn't work.
what i need is reading and writing files when ever i want in my program.

Comment: Then you need a more sophisticated solution than exp_popen(), I believe, as that only gives you one file - a read one. You can't read from and write to a single pipe - you need one for input, and one for output.

Comment: there must be a way, I think its possible to run exp with 0 time just so it will update the exp_buffer and read it from there but it seend like a workaround when there should be a simple way

Comment: Oh, I'm sure there is a way - just not using exp_popen, since as I said, pipes are one-way only.

Comment: unlike pipes, expect gives you bi-directional control

Answer (score 0):

found a way, after creating the connection the way i did, the shell is:

```
[root@sanblaze ~]#
```

i write a command to it using for example:

```
fputs("echo LinkReset > /port4/port\r" , fp);
exp_fexpectl(fp, exp_exact , "]# " , 1 , exp_end);
```

reading a files content with grep:

```
fputs("cat /port4/port | grep -w Mode\r" , fp);
exp_fexpectl(fp, exp_exact , "]# " , 1 , exp_end);
```

after doing the above the "exp_buffer" witch is a global variable holds all the text that came from the remote shell from the last time "exp_fexpectl" ran, witch means only the output of my command. all that's left is to parse it.